# Is it ever okay to format any part of the contents of an 'if' statement on the same line as the if statement itself?

Tags: python, if-statement, code-formatting

I'm doing some practice exercises for beginner Python, and I'm trying to nail down correct formatting, how to make your code clean and fast, and other stuff like that.

One thing I'm unsure of is `if` statements.

Here's how I usually do `if` statements:

```
if something:
    do (something)
```

But I've seen people do this:

```
if something:  do (something)
```

I've even seen this:

```
if something:  do (something)
    then do (something else)
```

I've also seen people do it with nested `if` statements, where each and every `if`/`elif`/`else` had the first line of code on the same line as the if/elif/else themselves.

Is it ever okay / proper form to do any of these other methods?

Comment: The third form doesn't actually work. You may have misunderstood what you saw, or you may have been looking at the work of people with really bad knowledge of Python.

Comment: I kind of figured. I was just making sure. They are all beginners like me, but the second one was actually an accepted solution on a coding challenge website, so I wanted to check it against more experienced people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to point you to the **The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters**, specifically items 1, 3, and 7.

```
$ python
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

1) Beautiful is better than ugly.
3) Simple is better than complex.
7) Readability counts.
```

There are lots of things you **can** do in Python that I'll bet many people wish you couldn't. I'd stick with the simplest, easiest to read code and you'll thank yourself in the future.

Comment: For me the most important style rule you'll find for Python or anything else - in PEP 8, [A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) - "sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment".

Answer (score 4):

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), a seminal style guide for Python, discourages this behavior:

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged.

It is typically valid syntax to do so, as long as there is only a single line involved, but it's considered a bad practice. Avoid it.

Comment: One issue with that logic - `if condition :` isn't a complete statement. `if condition : whatever()` is actually one compound statement. Sure it contains another simpler statement - that's what compound statements do. It's similar to the fact that the list `[1,2,3]` is a single value - it contains three other values but is still one compound value.

Comment: @Steve314 Be that as it may, PEP8 goes on to give `if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()` as an example of the proscribed behavior. Don't argue with me; I didn't come up with it. :)

Comment: Yes, but no style guide is perfect. If you're in a position where you have to follow the guide that's what you do, but for short conditions and short statements I'm invoking the PEP8 hobgoblins. There's no difference in readability either way for that one `if` statement but, for context, a line that's just off the bottom of the screen is clearly less readable than one you can see. Yeah, short functions etc - it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is the one I am used to:

```
x = 4

if (x%2) == 0:
    print "pair"
else:
    print "impair"
```

You must use "elif" (instead of "else if") for other alternatives. Hope it helps.